# If any zero coupon bond $P(T)$ can be chosen as a numéraire, then why can the rolling bond for any time discretization be chosen as numéraire

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, forward-rate, numeraire

Let us consider some finite time horizon $[0,T]$, and we assume that $P(t)$, the zero coupon bond maturing in $t$ for any $t\in [0,T]$ can be chosen as a numéraire, i.e. such that the numéraire-relative prices of traded assets are martingales.

Next, we define for a given time discretization of $\{0=T_{0}<...< T_{n}=T \}$, the rolling bond $R$ is defined as follows:

$$R(\{T_{0},...,T_{n} \};t):=P(T_{m(t)+1};t)\prod\limits_{i=0}^{m(t)}(1+L(T_{i},T_{i+1};T_{i})(T_{i+1}-T_{i}))$$

where $L(T_{i},T_{i+1}):= \frac{1}{T_{i+1}-T_{i}}\frac{P(T_{i})-P(T_{i+1})}{P(T_{i+1})}$, i.e. the forward rate and further

$$m(t):=\max\{i:T_{i}\leq t\} $$

Question: Why does it follow that indeed the rolling bond $R$ may also be chosen as a numéraire? That is we can associate a measure $\mathbb Q^{R}$ such that the $R$-relative prices of traded assets are martingales under that measure.

**Edit**:

I guess I should edit my question in the following way to be more precise:

Given that we know for every $t \in [0,T]$ the martingale measure $\mathbb Q^{P(t,\cdot)}$ exists, i.e. the dynamics of $\frac{S}{P(t,\cdot)}$ are driftless under $\mathbb Q^{P(t,\cdot)}$, where $S$ represents a traded asset, how do we know that $R$ necessarily has a martingale measure associated to it? In this particular case, the forwards $(L_{i})$ for the given time discretization are assumed to be the traded assets. In order for the rolling bond $R$ (for a given tenor discretization) to have an associated martingale measure $\mathbb Q^{R}$, we need to find the drift of the traded assets that render $\frac{S}{R}$ driftless under $\mathbb Q^{R}$.

Comment: The discrete money-market numeraire starts at 1 and compounds at the money-market rate ($\tau$ is the annual fraction).

$$\prod\limits_{i=0}^{n}(1+\tau L(T_{i},T_{i+1};T_{i}))$$

The rolling bond is about combining the zero-coupon bond numeraire and the discrete money-market numeraire. The spot zero coupon bond is taken and when it matures (at maturity, it is equal to 1), it basically turns into the classical discrete money-market numeraire that compounds using the formula you wrote.

Comment: Hi Jan, I think my initial question may have been misleading as this does not answer what I intended it to. Please see my edit for the updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rolling bond $R(t)$ as defined in your question is a valid *numéraire*. Indeed, this bond can synthetized with the following iterative trading strategy in basic assets:

1. At any time $T_i\in\{T_0,\dots,T_{m(t)-1}\}$, invest your available  wealth into the spot-starting zero-coupon bond expiring at $T_{i+1}$, with price $P(T_i,T_{i+1})$.
2. At $T_{i+1}$, you receive the proceeds from the investment made in 1, namely your initial wealth compounded by $1+\tau_iL(T_i,T_{i+1})$ where $\tau_i:=T_{i+1}-T_i$.
3. Repeat steps 1-2.

It is easy to see the above strategy is self-financing: once initiated at $T_0$ by investing your available wealth in $P(T_0,T_1)$, there is no need for any inflow or outflow of cash to carry on. It only requires buying basic assets, namely zero-coupon bonds, which are themselves valid *numéraires* with positive price processes. Therefore, the rolling bond is also a valid numéraire.

Alternatively, we can refer to the seminal paper by Geman et al. (1995) which established *numéraire* theory. Working on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ over the interval $[0,T]$, a *numéraire* is defined as follows:

> *Definition* 2. A numéraire is a price process $X(t)$ almost surely strictly positive for
> each $t\in[0,T]$.

The price process of any zero-coupon bond is strictly positive (note that the traded assets are the bonds $P$, not the forward rates $L$), hence the price process of the rolling bond is also positive $-$ thus $R$ is a valid *numéraire*. Moreover, per your edited question, you have assumed that a martingale measure exists for each of the zero-coupon bonds $P(\cdot,T_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ therefore Assumption 1 of their paper is fulfilled:

> *Assumption* 1. There exists a non-dividend-paying asset $n(t)$ and a probability $\pi$ equivalent to the initial probability $P$ such that for any basic security $S_k$ without intermediate payments, the price of $S_k$ relative to $n$, i.e. $S_k(t)/n(t)$, is a local martingale with respect to $\pi$.

You can then apply Theorem 1, which states that $R$ induces a new martingale measure $\mathbb{Q}^R$ equivalent to the other zero-coupon (i.e. forward) measures $\mathbb{Q}^{P(\cdot,T_1)},\dots,\mathbb{Q}^{P(\cdot,T_n)}$. You do not need to determine the drift of the assets under $\mathbb{Q}^R$ to determine whether such measure exists. Indeed, as long as you define the following Radon-Nikodym derivative to change between the zero-coupon(s) and the rolling measures:
$$\left.\frac{\text{d}\mathbb{Q}^R}{\text{d}\mathbb{Q}^{P(\cdot,T_i)}}\right|_{\mathscr{F}_{T_i}}=\frac{R(T_i)P(0,T_i)}{R(0)P(T_i,T_i)}=\frac{R(T_i)P(0,T_i)}{R(0)}$$
You know that any asset price divided by the *numéraire* $R$ will be a martingale under measure $\mathbb{Q}^R$, per the aforementioned Theorem.

The measure associated to the rolling bond is usually known as **spot measure** or **rolling measure**, see for example Proposition 6.3.3 in Brigo and Mercurio's book on interest rates. This measure was originally introduced by Jamashidian (1997). Another reference is Antonov & Lee (2004).

Often, the rolling measure is used in practice under Monte Carlo based pricing engines where the theoretical pricing measure should be the risk-neutral one: to avoid interpolation problems, a change of measure is performed from the risk-neutral measure to the rolling measure where the anchor points $T_1,\dots,T_n$ are chosen to match the simulation grid.

**References**

Antonov & Lee (2004). "Interest Rate Modelling Framework in Discrete Rolling Spot Measure", available at SSRN.

Brigo and Mercurio (2006). *Interest Rate Models — Theory and Practice*, Springer.

Geman, El Karoui and Rochet (1995). "Changes of Numéraire, Changes of Probability Measure and Option Pricing", *Journal of Applied Probability*, Vol. 32, No. 2, pp. 443-458.

Jamshidian (1997). "Libor and Swap Market Models and Measures", *Finance and Stochastics*, Vol. 1, pp. 293-330.

Comment: Thanks for the background information, but I cannot see how this answers my question: If $(\mathbb Q^{P(t;\cdot)})_{0 \leq t \leq T}$ are equivalent martingale measure then why is $\mathbb Q^{R}$ an equivalent martingale measure?

Comment: @user9078057 I misinterpreted your question due to that typo that you fixed. I added further details, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: ah thanks, I think I understood your original comment (please correct me if I am wrong): We can find a drift term for every tradeable asset such that its $R$-relative dynamics under $\mathbb Q^{R}$ is that of a martingale (i.e. drift is $0$). But it is not clear to me how this depends on the fact that for every $t \in [0,T]$ the $\mathbb Q^{P(t,\cdot)}$-dynamics of every  tradeable asset divided by $P(t,\cdot)$ is such that the tradeable asset has zero drift under $\mathbb Q^{P(t,\cdot)}$

Comment: @user9078057 added additional details based on the seminal paper by Geman, El Karoui and Rochet (1995) on _numéraires_ and changes of measure.

Comment: @user9078057 Basically: if you already assume a certain martingale measure exists for an asset $X$, and you have some other asset $Y$ with no dividends and strictly positive price, then you can define a new probability measure induced by $Y$ under which $Y$-relative dynamics of the other assets will be martingales.

Comment: thanks for your detailed edits and references. I have marked the question as correct, but I have one question that leads on from the answers you gave: How strict is the condition/assumption that the martingale measure $\mathbb Q^{P(t,\cdot)}$ exists for all $t \in [0,T]$? Is it simply assumed in all valuation/pricing settings? I'm just interested about the assumption.